# WordPress custom loop filter by meta_key and value with serialize data

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I am trying to run custom loop for Custom Post Type with filtering by some `meta_key` and `value`

Now simple meta value works fine but here I have a challenge with the below kind of serialized data (nested).

I am using [wpalchemy](https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy) for meta box. `meta_key` for the post type is `_event_meta` and `value` is as below

```
a:9:{s:19:"ac_event_operations";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Training";}s:18:"ac_event_positions";a:1:{i:0;s:10:"Supervisor";}s:18:"ac_event_employees";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"15";}s:13:"ac_event_date";s:10:"2017-06-15";s:19:"ac_event_start_time";s:5:"06:30";s:17:"ac_event_end_time";s:5:"07:00";s:14:"ac_event_place";s:6:"Office";s:18:"ac_event_organizer";s:4:"Jack";s:16:"ac_event_contact";s:4:"Rose";}
```

I am trying to filter `All Events` based on `ac_event_operations`, `ac_event_positions`, `ac_event_employees`

So for me, the challenge is to get events filtering with the value from above meta_keys. Here is the query I used but of course, it is not giving any result.

```
global $event_mb;
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $event_mb->get_the_id(), TRUE );

$paged    = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args     = [
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'meta_query'     => [
        'meta_key' => '_event_meta',
        'value'    => '%ac_event_employees%',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ],

];
$temp     = $wp_query;
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

philosophical opinion, people that store serialized data do not mean it to be used in searches.

If you need to search in that data, you should hook on the `save_post` hook (or whatever is relevant) and store whatever you need in a different meta in a way that can be used in search.

Side notes:

1. Searching in meta is not scalable
2. `LIKE` have horrible performance, if you get into the point of using it you should ask yourself where did you go wrong ;)

Comment: I understand what you say. I didn't realize before when I started using WPAlchemy library for the meta-box. Now I realized and learned that creating meta-boxes is the best option. That will gives maximum control in every aspect. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you find a soultion for that? I got into same place that some meta keys that is stored as serialized data needed to be searched/filtered.

Comment: @MaorBarazany I think that the only option is to "unpack" the serialized data with every field gaining its own meta field. In the long run this is the sanest option, but obviously this might be easier said then done if the code creating the meta is not under your control

Comment: Well, it appears that if you want only to check if a meta key exists inside the serialized array, and you don't matter for it's value, you may easily treat that serialized array of metakey as a string for this matter, and then in your WP meta_query you may use the key name as the key of the serialized array, the value as the key name that inside the serialized array of keys/values, and compare by LIKE.